# Responsive bootstrap design causing divs to shift with addition of help-block

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a noob in terms of css.

I have used Bootstrap Validator plugin from [here](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/settings/) along with [Bootstrap Rtl](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) in my asp.net web forms website.

My issue is that whenever there is an error in a field, some fields which are below the one which has error gets shifted & makes them look bad.

For Eg: 
a) Initial Placement of Fields.
[image]

b) Once there is an error/help-block added by bootstrap validator/on focus.
[image]
c) Focus to another field 
[image]
I would like to prevent this from happening. I believe this is a problem with bootstrap css. I tried using pull-right class on the drop down's parent div & it does not work

Here is my code shortened for brevity:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="الاسم الأول" AssociatedControlID="txtFirstName" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control OnlyArabic " placeholder="الاسم الأول" MaxLength="144" required
            data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال الاسم الأول"              
            ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMiddleName" runat="server" Text="اسم الأب" AssociatedControlID="txtMiddleName" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMiddleName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control OnlyArabic " placeholder="اسم الأب" MaxLength="144" required
            data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال اسم الأب"
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblThirdName" runat="server" Text="اسم الجد" AssociatedControlID="txtThirdName" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtThirdName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control OnlyArabic " placeholder="اسم الجد" MaxLength="144" required
             data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال اسم الجد "
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFamilyName" runat="server" Text="اسم العائلة" AssociatedControlID="txtFamilyName" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFamilyName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control OnlyArabic " placeholder="اسم العائله" MaxLength="144" required
            data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال اسم العائلة "
    </div>


    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblNationality" runat="server" Text="الجنسية" AssociatedControlID="ddlNationality" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNationality" runat="server" CssClass="MakeSelect2 form-control" DataSourceID="objDSNationality" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Code"
            data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال الجنسية" 
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblIdTypeCode" runat="server" Text="نوع الهوية" AssociatedControlID="ddlIdTypeCode" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIdTypeCode" runat="server" CssClass="MakeSelect2 form-control idType " DataSourceID="objDSIdTypeCode" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Code"
        data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال نوع الهوية" >
        </asp:DropDownList>    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
        <asp:Label ID="lblIDNo" runat="server" Text="رقم الهوية" AssociatedControlID="txtIDNo" CssClass="control-label" ></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtIDNo" runat="server" CssClass="form-control  AllowAlphaNumeric  idno" placeholder="رقم الهوية" MaxLength="10" required
            data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="الرجاء ادخال رقم الهوية" 
            ></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a `clearfix` class before the drop down div.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```